# Currency conversion in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, currency

How can I convert between currencies in Objective-C, using either the Cocoa or Cocoa Touch frameworks?

Comment: This is too broad a question. Break the problem down into steps ("get info from a web service", "parse info", "display info"), research each step, and post specific, pointed questions about the steps you couldn't figure out.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi: i agree, *unless* someone has already done the work for you ;)

Comment: Sacha is indeed a lucky fellow. ;-)

Comment: Sacha: If you're asking about one of the Apple sample projects, you need to specify that in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, aren't you a lucky fellow:

https://github.com/davedelong/DDUnitConverter

Simply copy the entire "DDUnitConverter" subfolder into your project, then do:

```
#import "DDUnitConverter.h"
#import "DDCurrencyUnitConverter.h"

- (void) convertCurrency {
  DDUnitConverter *converter = [DDUnitConverter currencyUnitConverter];
  NSNumber *from = [NSNumber numberWithInt:42];
  NSNumber *to = [converter convertNumber:from fromUnit:DDCurrencyUnitUKPoundSterling toUnit:DDCurrencyUnitUSDollar];
  NSLog(@"new value: %@", to);
}
```

That will convert £42 to USD$.

Rates are pulled from the [IMF](http://www.imf.org/external/index.htm) automatically, but if you *really* need to, you can invoke `-refreshExchangeRates` on your unit converter instance.

The `-convertNumber:fromUnit:toUnit:` call will block until the rates can be downloaded and parsed.  Subsequent calls will just use the already-downloaded exchange rates.

Comment: will it be updated resultes means current rates of the currencies.?

Comment: I have tried it, it doesn't give correct values, for instance 1$ gives 1.003(long decimal number) UAE Dirham while it should be 3.67.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I've choose:

https://github.com/davedelong/DDUnitConverter

Rates are pulled from the IMF but during the conversion , there are problems using NSDecimalNumber functions ( decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy and decimalNumberByDividingBy: they dont give the correct results if you dont use NSDecimalNumber var's created by strings), so I've correct the conversion method like this and now it work:

DDUnitConverter.m

```
- (NSNumber *)convertNumber:(NSNumber *)number fromUnit:(DDUnit)fromUnit toUnit:(DDUnit)toUnit {
    if (fromUnit == toUnit) { return number; }

    //make sure it's an NSDecimalNumber
    NSDecimalNumber *source = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[number decimalValue]];

    NSDecimalNumber *convertToBaseUnit = [[self class] multiplierForUnit:fromUnit];

    NSDecimalNumber * n1 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[source stringValue]];
    NSDecimalNumber * n2 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[convertToBaseUnit stringValue]];

    NSDecimalNumber *valueInBaseUnit = [n1 decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:n2];

    NSDecimalNumber *convertFromBaseUnit = [[self class] multiplierForUnit:toUnit];
    if ([convertFromBaseUnit isEqual:[NSDecimalNumber zero]]) {
        convertFromBaseUnit = [NSDecimalNumber one];
    }
    NSDecimalNumber * n3 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[valueInBaseUnit stringValue]];
    NSDecimalNumber * n4 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[convertFromBaseUnit stringValue]];

    NSDecimalNumber *valueInTargetUnit = [n3 decimalNumberByDividingBy:n4];

    return valueInTargetUnit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative, is to use the YQL (Yahoo Query Language) to retrieve the latest rates. 
Yahoo's dev site makes it pretty easy to get started in Objective-C and there are plenty of SO examples on YQL. 
http://developer.yahoo.com/social/sdk/objectivec/

You may find Yahoo is very nice and liberal with their terms & conditions for many of their data APIs. It's also a lot less fragile than a non dedicated API like Dave is using. Dave writes great code, but the IMF TSV file is not nearly as guaranteed to be available as the YQL services.